# Socket programming; shall I use pInvoke or write c# version of existing c++ app

Tags: c#-3.0, pinvoke, sockets

I have been assigned to a task where I need to connect to a socket and receive a lot of updates (3K-4K messages per second) I also need to send some message to server for authentication and configuration.

There is an existing C++ apps given by the data provider and they have no c# sample. I have been trying to write this app with C# but having some difficulties; especially with marshalling structs containing variable length arrays etc.. Am I on the right path to do this?

I have been advised to use PInvoke but looks like I need to first modify their C++ sample to make it API like and then I can invoke it C# properly. And I am not sure about the performance with PInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use C++ if the app is already in that?
If there is a reason to use C# I would always re-write the C++ if it is feasable. You would be writing new code in C# so you may as well do a complete migration rather than a cumbersome mixture.
I certainly wouldn't use pinvoke for something like network programming... it's complicated enough as it is without adding that. There's an inevitable performance hit with it although what that is exactly, "it depends".

Comment: The same way I commented on the kgiannakakis answer, @user243357, it is true that P/Invoke has its drawbacks, but the whole .NET Framework is based on that. And it may not be otherwise. Every program in an OS can interoperate with hardware only via the OS kernel (unless they're drivers or kernel-mode programs, and none of those could be coded in a managed language, such as C#), and so they all have to perform syscalls to the kernel. P/Invoke is the CLR model and implementation for syscalls, and no other option is possible until you're running under a runtime that implements CLI.

Comment: Indeed, everything uses P/Invoke. Look at the .NET reference source. The only thing that makes your code managed other than the C# language memory model is the precious job of people who worked at the .NET Framework, who worked hard at keeping the safe CLR memory model and principles building a complex workflow over the wrapper they had to build for the Windows kernel via P/Invoke calls.

Answer (score 0):

P/Invoke has a performance penalty. C# has a very nice networking programming model and I really suggest that you give it another try. The benefit will be that you have a fully managed, more efficient and maintainable application.

Of course if the existing application is huge and you need a lot of time to port it to C#, you could consider p/invoke. However, since you still need to modify it, you lose some of the advantages of this route.

Comment: Can you a bit elaborate on c#'s "networking programming model"

Comment: You can easily find a lot of information in Google. Everything is done with streams and in my opinion the big advantage is that you can have asynchronous calls for when data are received.

Comment: In case you missed it, @kgiannakakis, C# is a managed language that runs under a VM (which is CLR), and as such, it cannot directly interoperate with the hardware. So, the fully managed sockets and the P/Invoke drawback you're talking about are non-sense, considering that everything is implemented with P/Invoke to communicate with the Windows kernel (the so-called syscalls, or system calls). Take a look at the .NET Framework reference source if you don't believe me: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,c84007a498b38b5f